# I am running open varnish image from docker hub on EC2 linux, how to enable varnish logging?

Tags: linux, caching, amazon-ec2, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have Default.vcl with host and port and copied to container varnish:/etc/varnish
I am able to hit back end via varnish, but could not trace varnish logs using docker logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs in Varnish are not produced by the main `varnishd` process.

- You can either use the `varnishlog` binary to get in-depth logs
- Or you can use the `varnishncsa` binary to get Apache-style logs

You have to run either of these commands within your container, on the shell. Unfortunately this cannot be done through `docker logs`.

Answer (score 0):

Thijs's answer is correct, I would also recommend looking at the [varnishncsa service in the package](https://github.com/varnishcache/pkg-varnish-cache/blob/weekly/systemd/varnishncsa.service) to understand how you can run it from the same container, and [this blog post](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/varnish-docker) to understand what needs to be shared between the two containers if you decide to split them.